# Print result of two different controllers in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I'm starting in AngularJS, and I'm trying to create a very simple program, where a user can choose your favorite fruit and the result is shown below.

This choice can be performed in two different ways: through 3 quick buttons or typing a name in the text entry. These two modes have different controllers.

When I'm using the buttons works well, but not with the text editor.

I want to transfer the name written in the text entry for the controller1 and print the result.

My code is:

```
<html ng-app="myApp">
    <head>
        <title>Fruits</title>
        <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.19/angular.js"></script>
        <script>
            var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);


            app.service('simpleService', function() {

              var _fruit = 'None :(';

              var addFruit = function(newObj) {
                    console.log(newObj);
                  _fruit = newObj;
              }

              var getFruit = function(){
                  return _fruit;
              }

              return {
                addFruit: addFruit,
                getFruit: getFruit
              };
            })



            app.controller('controller1',function($scope, simpleService){

                $scope.fruit = simpleService.getFruit();

                $scope.fruitApple = function(){
                    $scope.fruit ='Apple';
                }

                $scope.fruitPear = function(){
                    $scope.fruit ='Pear';
                }

                $scope.fruitBanana = function(){
                    $scope.fruit ='Banana';
                }
            })

            app.controller('controller2', function($scope, simpleService){
                $scope.fruit2 = 'Other?';

                $scope.fruitEditor = function(f){
                    if(angular.isString(f)){
                        $scope.fruit2 = f;
                        simpleService.addFruit(f);
                    }
                }               
            });
        </script>

    </head>

    <body>
        <div ng-controller="controller1">
            <button ng-click="fruitPear()">Pear</button>
            <button ng-click="fruitApple()">Apple</button>
            <button ng-click="fruitBanana()">Banana</button>
            <br/>
            <br/>

            <div ng-controller="controller2">
                Edit:
                <input type="text" ng-change="fruitEditor(fruit2)" ng-model="fruit2">
            </div>

            <h5>Favorite fruit: {{fruit}}</h5>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are setting fruit value on initial load only. If you wanted to keep it sync with whatever you have inside service you should call `getFruit` method of service on view, so that it will get latest value from service on each digest cycle to ensure it correct.

```
$scope.getFruit = simpleService.getFruit;
```

on view

```
<h5>Favorite fruit: {{getFruit()}}</h5>
```

Same thing applies to while setting a rule, you shouldn't be adding `fruit` in scope variable, just put them inside service variable by calling `addFruit` method.

```
simpleService.addFruit('Apple');
```